# Do not play mp3 by Rhythmbox

Tags: sound, rhythmbox, mp3, edubuntu

I have newly install edubuntu 14.04 LTS OS in my hp laptop. Now installing all the required software. But while playing **mp3** files, it is informed that some **plug in** will be installed. But while try to install the same errors may occurs . I tried several times , but problem is same.

No mp3 file play with Rhythmbox. How is it minimized?

Comment: What is the name of the plugin that need to be installed? You can install it manually via terminal by run this command `sudo apt-get install package` . Remove package with that plugins name. If you need to install more than one package, run `sudo apt-get install package1 package 2` etc. Make sure you're connected to the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Open a shell terminal window and run this supercommand:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get check && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras ubuntu-restricted-addons librhythmbox-core8 libmad0 libmpg123-0 --reinstall -y && sudo apt-get autoremove -y
```

...then restart your computer and try again. If Rhythmbox still can't play MP3, install **Audacious** and **VLC Media Player**:

```
sudo apt-get install audacious vlc
```

...then try playing MP3 with VLC or Audacious. They're both excelent media players: Audacious plays audio tracks, VLC plays audio, video and even images.